# Adobe air 3+ Security Sandbox Violation for youtube api player

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, youtube-api

I am attempting to bring a chromeless youtube api player into an adobe air application, but it constantly throws Security Sandbox Violation errors and this is enough to break the program(listeners pause and tweens break). Is there any way to allow domains for adobe air applications? I've been searching around and have found solutions for regular swfs, but can't find anything for air. Supposedly air allows all, but I still get errors constantly.

Anyone know how to prevent Security Sandbox Violations in adobe air when using youtube api?

Comment: Just for added context is this being deployed/tested as mobile or as a desktop app (I'm not a youtube API user but figure may help to get an answer).  Also may want to link to the youtube API you're using as I believe there's a few versions.

Comment: Actually did a bit of searching around and it looks like this may actually be a lost cause if things haven't changed since Jan 2011 https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/Onn6atdaMJU

Comment: it's a desktop app. I came across those messages as well but was hoping someone might have new info. Guess I'll end up making it all local. This is my project: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z24IMcCpGiQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: oh, and this is the api https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

catch error using following code... put this in starting

```
try {Security.allowDomain("*");}catch (e) { };
```